# Trying to scrape iframe using beautifulsoup

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I wanted to scrape a video, but beautifulsoup doesn't wait for the iframe to load. I tried using selenium, but the google webdriver waits for the whole page to load and it takes forever. I also couldn't get the page source after the page was finished loading.

This was my code I tried with beautifulsoup, but I get nothing

```
def get_vidCode_from_source(source_url):
    source_code = requests.get(source_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"html.parser")
    print(soup.find('iframe'))

get_vidCode_from_source('http://anilinkz.io/one-piece-episode-769?src=3')
```

So tried getting the video link here in the iframe:

[image]

What would be good to be able to get iframes besides selenium?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract? Just the link to the iframe or the link to the video? By the sound of the name of your function maybe a code that relates to the video?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to get the video link. But it would also be good if I got the whole iframe element code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little bit old but for using selenium and getting the page source use this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://anilinkz.io/one-piece-episode-769?src=3')
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
browser.close()
for x in soup.find_all('iframe'):
    print(x)
```